# Rename multiple files in a folder using cmd

Tags: cmd

I am using Windows 7. I have many jpg images in one folder with alpha numeric number(PF1235, PF1236,EF1237, EF1238 etc.) & i would like to keep only numeric part as a file name. Alphabets are similar in most of the files like there are many starts with PF/EF/GF etc. followed by the different numbers.
Please suggest how do i remove these Alphabets from all the files?

Answer (score 0):

This should work - if you have lower case alpha characters then add `abcdef` etc after the `XYZ`

Test it on samples of your files first.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.jpg /b /a-d') do (
    for /f "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%b in ("%%~na") do ren "%%a" "%%b%%~xa"
)
```